# Symfony 3: doctrine:generate:entities ignoring property type for default value

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.3

I'm having trouble with the Doctrine entities generator used on Symfony 3 project with XML ORM definitions file rather than entities annotations.

When specifying the default value for field like on the examples below:

```
<field name="isDeleted" column="is_deleted" type="boolean">
  <options>
    <option name="default">false</option>
  </options>
</field>
<field name="priority" column="priority" type="integer">
  <options>
    <option name="default">0</option>
  </options>
</field>
```

results in generated entity that it has the default values for properties assigned as a ***string*** rather than proper ***integer*** or ***boolean*** value specified in the configuration.

The entity properties looks like the following:

```
/**
 * @var boolean
 */
private $isDeleted = 'false';

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $priority = '0';
```

What am I doing wrong? How to fix it?

Thanks for any help and ideas.

Comment: private $isDeleted = false;

Comment: I know how to correct it manually. I'm asking how to make the entities generator work properly.

Comment: Okay.  The solution is simple: don't use the rather silly generator in the first place.  Which I know does not help you out much.  But the generator is just to get you started.  It has many other more serious issues.

Comment: Silly or not, simply saving a lot of time that you have to spend on writing boilerplate code. This is not a place to argue about that. As said - again, if there is a solution to fix the above in XML declaration, then even more time can be saved. Surely I'm not the first one facing such issue.

Comment: Personally, I think the best approach to saving time writing boilerplate code is to not write boilerplate code in the first place.